# React Native - Navigating two screen using two different fetch request

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, react-navigation

I'm new in react native. I'm creating a flatlist which contains a category buttons of foods, and once click a category button a second page will be display containing a kinds of foods depending on what category button the user clicks.

The names of the category button is load from my database, so I have a fetch for that. Now, as I've said I have to display a second page once a button is clicked.

I've already done a code where there is 2 kinds of fetch request for displaying my category name in the button and for navigating to the second page using the other fetch.

The problem is; once a category button is clicked, my button won't display any second page.

Here is my code

categories.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableHighlight, View,
StyleSheet, Platform, FlatList, AppRegistry,
TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

var screen = Dimensions.get('window');*/

export default class Categories extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Product2'
    };

    state = {
        data: [],
    };


    fetchData = async() => {
        const response_Cat = await fetch('http://192.168.254.102:3307/Categories/');
        const category_Cat = await response_Cat.json();
        this.setState({data: category_Cat});
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    };

    FoodCat = async() => {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.navigate('state');
        const response_Food = await fetch('http://192.168.254.102:3307/foods/' + params.id);
        const food_Food = await response_Food.json();
        this.setState({data: food_Food});
    };
    componentDidCatch() {
        this.FoodCat();
    };

  render() {
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      const { params } = this.props.navigation.navigate('state');
      return (
          <View style = { styles.container }>
              <FlatList
                data = { this.state.data }
                renderItem = {({ item }) =>
                    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}
                        onPress = { () => navigate('FoodCat', { id: item.id }) }>{ item.cat_name }</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>                    
                }
                keyExtractor={(x,i) => i}
              />
          </View>
      );
  }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Categories', () => Categories);
```

Details.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet,
FlatList, Text, View }
from 'react-native';

export default class Details extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            dataSource: []
        }
    }

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <View style = {{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text>
                        {item.menu_desc}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                        {item.menu_price}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://192.168.254.102:3307/foods/'
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson); 
            this.setState({
                dataSource: responseJson.data
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.dataSource)
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.navigate('state');
        return (
            <View style = { styles.container }>
                <FlatList
                    data = { this.state.dataSource }
                    renderItem = {this.renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Details', () => Details);
```

Comment: Where did you define your `navigation`? is it `StackNavigation`?

Comment: I think you mean this " import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; " if yes, It is located at my App.js sir

Comment: Did you try console.log in your onPress, is it really being called when tapping on the list item? and make sure that your key to the next screen (FoodCat) is correct i.e same as the one defined in the App.js.

Comment: Ahhm the listview is working when I change the navigate('FoodCat', { id: item.id }) into " navigate('Details', { .... } ". But now, I got a blank out put, the header is there but the kinds of food is not showing.

Comment: I've got it! I just made two function in my backend, the first one is containing the category with Select from table, and the other is menu with Select from table id. The id is the relationship between the two table.